# how to monitor regions for beacons using only UUID (kontakt beacons) for android:

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

i am using Kontakt beacons for android.[here](http://docs.kontakt.io/android-sdk/eclipse-files.zip) is the link for SDK i am using. There is only a single constructor for region accepting all the params namely minor, major , uuid and region identifier. I want to monitor a region based on only UUID and the start monitoring method from example [here](http://docs.kontakt.io/android-sdk/quickstart/) accepts only region as parameter and parameter set. Please guide me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Kontakt SDK. What you can do is range beacons on all UUIDs, then filter it according to what you want on the `RangingListener`. This is how you range all beacons:

```
    beaconManager.startRanging(Region.EVERYWHERE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor in that way [from the documentation](https://developer.kontakt.io/android-sdk/3.2.0/quickstart/):

```
Collection<IBeaconRegion> beaconRegions = new ArrayList<>();

IBeaconRegion region = new BeaconRegion.Builder()
    .identifier("My second Region")
    .proximity(UUID.fromString("6565d504-e306-4119-8266-0f8d4401cd0a"))
    .major(BeaconRegion.ANY_MAJOR) //any major, default value
    .minor(BeaconRegion.ANY_MINOR) //any minor, default value
    .build();

beaconRegions.add(region);

proximityManager.spaces().iBeaconRegions(beaconRegions);
```